# array 1D i need to ask the user to check index and print value

Tags: c++, arrays

I have to ask the user for a number and check whether the number is present in the array or not I wrote my code but it doesn't seem to be working we are not allowed to use find function or any other built in function since we are not taught any of this in class yet . Here is the exact question from my assignment and the code I have written till yet.

```
`l= [13, 99, 6, 76, 11, 83, 27, 84, 28, 67, 66, 22, 96, 46, 63, 21, 65, 48, 8, 14 , 84, 22, 28, 11, 83, 87, 11, 76, 6,83,27]`
```

**question: Write a program to search a given element in the array.**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int x;
    int i, j;
    int array[31] = {13, 99, 6, 76, 11, 83, 27, 84, 28, 67, 66, 22, 96, 46, 63, 21, 65, 48, 8, 14 , 84, 22, 28, 11, 83, 87, 11, 76, 6, 83, 27};

    for(i = 0; i <= 31; i++){
        for( j = 0; j <= 
            cout << "enter the number to locate in array";
            cin >> x; 

            if(array[i] == x){
                cout << x << "found at [" << i << "]" << "\n";
            }       
            else{   
                cout << "the number was not found in the array" << endl;
            }
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [I suggest you read about formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), and try again. Be sure to examine the preview before posting as well.

Comment: @StoryTeller tysm i am new I am learning :)

Comment: @lyb Doesn't matter. We all are equal on SO, and requirements for questions are the same for all. For instance - What is your question? I can see what you have to do, but there is no question in your "question". Please take the [tour], read through [help], and [ask].

Comment: You should get rid of the inner `for`, move your input option above the other `for`, add a `break` in the `if` and move the`else` below your loop, changing its condition to `if(i == sizeof(array)/sizeof(int[0])`, oh and `for(i = 0; i <= 31; i++)` -> `for(i = 0; i < 31; i++)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a simple example you can declare a `boolean` variable so inside loop if the value at least found once then assign it `true` otherwise if the loop returns and the value not found then inform the user that search not found.

Also you do not need an inner loop only one loop and input the search value outside the loop.

Also if you need the string comment mark in your string text you must precede it with backslash: "Hello there \"how are you?" otherwise the compiler thinks the string ends at the first double-quoted comma: "Hello there" then `how are you` undeclared identifier.

The program can look like:

```
int x;
bool isFound  = false;
int array[31] = {13, 99, 6, 76, 11, 83, 27, 84, 28, 67, 66, 22, 96, 46, 63, 21, 65, 48, 8, 14 , 84, 22, 28, 11, 83, 87, 11, 76, 6, 83, 27};

cout << "enter the number to locate in array";
cin >> x;

for(int i = 0; i < 31; i++){ //here: don't write i <= 31
    if(array[i] == x){
        isFound = true;
        cout << x << " found at: " << i << endl;
    }
}

if(!isFound)
    cout << "The value doesn't exist in the array!" << endl;
```

- Arrays are indexed from `0` to `n - 1` not `n` so if you write `array[n]` is an `Undefined behavior` Because the memory doesn't belong to it.